# Boolean Union couldn't be executed

Tags: modifiers

I have two meshes which I believe to be manifold.  Blender union says it can't be executed. In searching for an answer, interior or duplicate faces were suggested as a problem.  I don't remember encountering that as a problem before.  If that is the problem, it would severely limit the usefulness of Blender to me, and probably many other users who may be equally unaware of having created interior or duplicate faces, or may be frustrated by the time spent trying to avoid or eliminate such constructs.
[Trimx file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3qdn1ebv74xnsk/Trimx.blend?dl=0)

Comment: the topology of your object seems a bit messy but if you give the boolean to the bottom object it seems to work. Then you'll have to apply and to clean a bit with a Remove Doubles

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  I gather that I need to upgrade to 2.78 to get this to work?   2.74 currently.

Comment: I tried with 2.79 but it should work with your version

Comment: Upgraded to 2.79 and the union appeared to work.  However, the result is apparently non-manifold????  Now what?  In my simple mind, the union of two manifold objects should result in one manifold object.

Comment: I think bugs happen with boolean, especially with messy meshes. Yes you are right, I missed that, it looks like after the boolean it is non-manifold and impossible to fix with the Clean-Up function. So, maybe someone will answer differently but it looks like you don't have other choice than rebuild a clean mesh, and avoid boolean.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and patience.  Big rethink coming.